# issue while json parsing in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have an array like this comming from php file with json_encode.

```
[{"label":"Mississippi State, Mississippi","value":"mississ"},
 {"label":"Mississauga, Ontario","value":"mississ"},
 {"label":"Mississippi Station, Ontario","value":"mississ"}]
```

This array is dynamic. I want to alert the label of this array.

JQUERY:

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
alert(obj.label);
```

It's giving me error like obj is null.

EDIT:

basically I want to put these values in dropdown search box: like this jquery [plugin](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#folding)

AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "ajax/ir_populate_search.php",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                keyword: request.term,
                path: path
            },

 success: function(data){
    var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
    var availableCities = obj.label;
    $( "#txtLocation" ).autocomplete({
                    source: availableCities
                });
}
```

Comment: can you give your ajax call code cause if you don't use dataType:json then your data don't have the response string. its in data.responseText. Try $.parseJSON(data.responseText);

Comment: check my edit.. I am using json dataType..

Comment: Why are you doing parseJson of a json object ? i mean data is already the json.

Comment: `dataType: "json"` tells jQuery to parse it for you.  `data` is *already* parsed.  `data` is an array of objects.

Comment: you do not need to parse json its already in parsed format .. call directly like data.label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to parse json, it is already json. Use this;

```
$( "#txtLocation" ).autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax/ir_populate_search.php",
            data: {
                    keyword: request.term,
                    path: path
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function( data ) {
                response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                    return {
                        label: item.label,
                        value: item.value
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: It works for me.. Just one problem here. I can not select the search results. It should populate in text box after selecting.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, you already have a structure that you can work with, but it is not an `Object` . . . it's an array of `Objects`, so, to access the `label` parameter, you need to identify which object you want to look at, by providing its index, like this:

```
data[n].label
```

Using your example, you would get these values, for the various indexes:

- data[0].label ==> Mississippi State, Mississippi
- data[1].label ==> Mississauga, Ontario
- data[2].label ==> Mississippi Station, Ontario

So, to loop through them all and get the data for each entry, you could do something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    . . . do something with: data[i].label . . .
    . . . do something with: data[i].value . . .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jquery for using a json object in javascript

Try something like that:

```
$data = [{"label":"Mississippi State, Mississippi","value":"mississ"},
         {"label":"Mississauga, Ontario","value":"mississ"},
         {"label":"Mississippi Station, Ontario","value":"mississ"}]

$data[0].label
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do this `dataType: "json"`, jQuery does JSON parsing for you, so `data` is already a JavaScript object. Remove `var obj = $.parseJSON(data);` and work with `data` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Data is already the json object [**$.parseJSON**](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) is used to parse the JSON string to an object
Like this:

```
$.parseJSON('[{"label":"Mississippi State, Mississippi","value":"mississ"},{"label":"Mississauga, Ontario","value":"mississ"},{"label":"Mississippi Station, Ontario","value":"mississ"}]')
```

Just using data and adding to the array the values you're using will work

```
$.ajax({
            url: "ajax/ir_populate_search.php",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                keyword: request.term,
                path: path
            },success: function(data){
           //data is already the array of objects
           //just loop them 

            var availableCities = [];
            for(i in data){
              availableCities.push(data[i].label)
            }


           $( "#txtLocation" ).autocomplete({
                    source: availableCities
                });
}
})
```